# AWS ElastiCache redis operations take more than 10 ms

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm seeing very high latency on AWS elastic cache redis GETs/SETs. Using one instance of redis (cache.r3.2xlarge). The rate of redis requests which includes set_type_commands, get_type_commands and hash_based_commands is around 3k rps.

SET function is a simple SET operation whereas GET function is pipeline of 3 commands (2 HGET and 1 GET). Please let me know if I'm missing something. More than 10% of requests to redis are taking more than 10 msec. AFAIK 3k rps is very less for redis and should perform significantly better.

Measuring time on SET function and GET function.

Comment: Looks like you have big latency. Is there an instrument to move instances closer to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Cache.r3.2xlarge is a very expensive instance for such a load, It should not take more than 3-4ms, to respond.

You should do the below-mentioned things:-

1. Monitor the Redis instance through [cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html).
2. Check the Redis slow query logs.

[slowlog length](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog)

```
slowlog get 200
1) (integer) 13
   2) (integer) 1309448128
   3) (integer) 30
   4) 1) "slowlog"
      2) "get"
      3) "100"
```

Will help you to check the slow queries that are affecting your Redis's overall performance.

go through it :- https://redis.io/commands/slowlog

Comment: Cloud watch metrics looks fine (Is there something specific I need to check?). P99 is around 6ms, but metrics looks like sawtooth. Sometimes I see spikes where the call to redis takes around/more than 15ms. Any suggestions?

Comment: Another important point, when our service runs on 3 instances timeouts or more, when we bump up the instances to 10 redis performs much better performance.